# Restrict User from entering the same range of values in saving through a loop - Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a grid in which the user can add many rows as he wants. The user will select a type and against that type he will enter a minimum value and a maximum value. Now since he can add many rows as he wants, enters the desired ranges and presses the save button. All the rows will be saved by going through a loop.

I want to restrict the user or show a message somehow while saving that if he has eneterd the same range against that type. Then the system should not allow to do so. how can I do so?

here is how I am saving the values in a loop using jquery. I want to do something here

```
if ($.trim($(this).find('td:eq(0)').html()) != "No Data.") {
   TableGrid += $(this).attr('pkid') + "♥";
   TableGrid += $(this).find('td:eq(1)').find('select').val() + "♥";
                    
   color.push(
     '#' + $.jPicker.List[index].color.active.val('hex') + "♥"); //push value in array here index will be 0, 1..etc
     TableGrid += '#' + $.jPicker.List[index].color.active.val('hex') + "♥";
     TableGrid  += $(this).find('td:eq(3)').find('input').val() + "♥";
     TableGrid += $(this).find('td:eq(4)').find('input').val() + "♥";
     TableGrid += "♠";
```

Comment: Working exemple ?